# Gunicorn/flask API to expose an sklearn model not working

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, gunicorn

I can't seem to figure this out. I've got a model trained with scikit-learn, saved to a .pkl file, and I want to make an API that would make predictions based on it.

I already have the code that makes predictions and it runs fine from console/unit-tests. To speed up predictions I'm splitting the data (thousands of image patches) and spreading the load using `joblib`/`multiprocessing`.

I'm setting `JOBLIB_START_METHOD=forkserver` since scikit-learn hangs if used from within a `multiprocessing` process.

I've got an API done with `flask` which uses this code, and when run with flask's dev server it works just fine. Now I'm trying to host the `flask` app within `gunicorn` and it's not working at all.

If I use the default workers, then it just hangs with no errors when trying to predict, much like if I hadn't set the 'forkserver' multiprocessing. I'm running `gunicorn` like this:

`JOBLIB_START_METHOD=forkserver gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --timeout 3600 web.app:app`

I also tried using the `gevent` backend. This actually does work but it's very slow, and it prints this:

`Multiprocessing backed parallel loops cannot be nested below threads, setting n_jobs=1`

So, any ideas on getting this to work in a way that there's multiple web workers running (I don't think that's the case with flask's dev server) and with a request being able to leverage `joblib`/`multiprocessing`? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gevent won't work with joblib since it spawns thread(s) to handle requests concurrently (Refer this [discussion](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1488)) and that's what your warning actually says. Secondly, it's very slow because joblib converts your parallel calls into sequential calls and executes them (Refer to this [discussion](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/180)).

I did the face the same problem while performing parallelism using joblib. Although I didn't use sklearn, I think the following command should work for you as well:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$SERVICE_PORT --workers=2 -t $SERVICE_TIMEOUT rest_api:app
```

If you want to have a look at the complete source code, you can follow it 
[here](https://github.com/fabric8-analytics/fabric8-analytics-stack-analysis/pull/140).